# NextJS getInitialProps called twice by babel asyncToGenerator

Tags: express, routes, babeljs, router, next.js

I realised my getInitialProps called twice (even thrice), one is user's request while the other is from babel asyncToGenerator like this:

```
localhost/[page]/babel/runtime-corejs2/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js
localhost/[page]/internal/process/task_queues.js
```

these two requests has broke my page when user try to open the page, because getInitialProps function should fetch data from mongodb based on ID after the page_name e.g: `localhost/[page]/[id]`.

In above cases, the `id` is `babel` and `internal`, therefore there is no returned data.
Worst, these two requests happened at the same time when user requested the page, so the page will never be opened bcs of these two requests disturb the response that should be received by the component. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After 2 days dealing with this issue, I remove the issue by editing the express route. Previously I put `*?` at the end of the url in order to receive whatever parameters behind the path.

Here is what it looks like before I edit:

```
app.get("/:page/:id*?", () => {});
```

Then I modified it to become:

```
app.get("/:page/:id", () => {});
```

That two characters solve my issue, eventhough it means my page would not be able to receive any parameters, but for now it works like a charm.